# Obtain DLL file versions in projects in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, dll, tfs

I have created a tool in WPF for our developers to easily keep track of specific DLLs. This way they know which projects have outdated DLLs (or a DLL version that is not being widely implemented, say 2.2 but we are on 2.1). Right now it scans through the directories, provided a starting point, to obtain information about the specified DLLs.

This works very well, but a question was raised if this could be done directly through TFS API. I am wondering if it is possible to obtain file versions without having to map/obtain latest version. In other words, to cycle through all the projects (in their latest version) and collect the version numbers of the DLLs directly through the TFS API. One way could be to simply have someone map all the projects onto the hard drive and run the tool on the root directly. However, this is not very convenient.

I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution to this, though it requires you to download the files down from TFS. In any case, you will need a user account so that you can find the DLL files. Here is a few snippets of code:

To obtain a list of the DLL files:

```
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfcollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("URL"), new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"));
        VersionControlServer server = tfcollection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        //Obtain all DLLs. You can narrow this down to the specific one's you want
        ItemSet items = server.GetItems("$/*.dll", RecursionType.Full);
```

To download the files, I simplified things a little bit to make it easier. To cycle through the files, you can:

```
        foreach (Item item in items.Items)
```

Now you want to download the files. This is slow, but stops the algorithm from recreating the TFS folder structure:

```
       string[] split = item.ServerItem.ToString().Split('/');

       //This may not work if you have files in the root
       item.DownloadFile(split[split.Length - 1]);
```

This will download your DLL file so that you can extract data out of it. Unfortunately, you cannot do this directly through TFS, so we need a copy. Now that you do, you can extrac the DLL version:

```
     FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(localFileLocation).FileVersion
```

The way you present data is obviously up to you. For simplicity, I just dump the version numbers with the item.ServerItem into a text file.

Hope this helps if anyone is looking for something similar!